# How to customize the protocol in http-component 4.5.3

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-httpcomponents

In 3.1 version I have done this to customize the protocol configuration

Protocol pro= new Protocol("https",new EasyprotocolSocketFactory,443);

Protocol.registerProtocol("https", pro);

I am not getting how to do the same with 4.5.3 version

Answer (score 0):

This example could help for creating custom SSL context if this is what you are looking for:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

Comment: I have one more doubt, is there any way to set port and host name for http-client object in latest version

Comment: Please provide the code you tried so that we could help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436416/in-httpcomponets-4-5-is-there-any-way-to-set-host-and-port